# Problema Anomaly Detection Twitter package, data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

Tags: r, datatable, twitter, packages

Buenas a todos. He estado intentando utilizar el paquete de detección de anomalías de Twitter para el lenguaje R disponible [aquí](https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection/). Mi problema radica en que intentando emular los ejemplos de Twitter con una base de datos en la que me encuentro trabajando disponible [aquí](http://robjhyndman.com/data/turkey_elec.csv/) me da un resultado muy inesperado. El script que estoy utilizando es este:

```
library(readr)
t <- as.data.frame(read_csv("D:/Descargas/turkey_elec.csv", 
          col_names = FALSE))

library(AnomalyDetection)
AnomalyDetectionVec(t, max_anoms=0.02, period=365, direction='both', only_last=FALSE, plot=TRUE)
```

y me arroja el siguiente resultado :

```
$anoms
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

$plot
NULL
```

He mirado en internet y me he encontrado con gente que tiene el mismo problema pero hasta ahora ninguna respuesta. ¿Ha alguien mas le ha sucedido?
¿Pueden ayudarme? ¿Algún otro paquete o código para series univariadas en R?

Muchas gracias a todo aquel que se tome el tiempo de leer mi problema.

Buen día.

Comment: Pero no es rara esa respuesta? Le he pasado algortimos de detección de anomalías menos robustos  y los pequeños picos los coge como una anomalía, que me parece  lo mas razonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema, que en realidad tampoco es un problema, es que en los datos de tu ejemplo `AnomalyDetectionVec()` no encuentra ninguna anomalía, por lo cual obtienes ese mensaje. El retorno de la función es una lista de dos elementos, uno es `plot` que es el gráfico y el otro es `anoms` que es un `data.frame` con el conjunto de valores anómalos. Al hacer:

```
res <- AnomalyDetectionVec(t, max_anoms=0.02, period=365, direction='both', only_last=FALSE, plot=TRUE

res$anoms
```

Obtienes justamente:

```
> data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

Es decir `anoms` esta vacío, no se han detectado anomalías. Lo que puedes hacer para probar la función, es forzar una anomalía, por ejemplo:

```
t$Valor[417] <- t$Valor[417]*3 # Triplicamos un valor cualquiera
res <- AnomalyDetectionVec(t, max_anoms=0.02, period=365, direction='both', only_last=FALSE, plot=TRUE)
res$anoms
res$plot
```

El resultado:

```
 index    anoms
1   417 48653.12
```

Y el gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, como bien te preguntas, ¿por qué no detecta varias anomalías evidentes? Hay que pensar en la naturaleza de los datos, estamos hablando de consumo eléctrico, tenemos mediciones diarias, sabemos que el consumo va a tener una tendencia a crecer y la demanda sera estacional en el año. En general, cuando se habla de consumo eléctrico o de gas, la estacionalidad se mide por trimestre, lógicamente por las estaciones que al variar la temperatura sin duda variará la demanda. En tu ejemplo, estás haciendo un análisis anual: `period=365`, lo más óptimo sería hacerlo por trimestre: `period=round(365/4)` y el otro tema es establecer el período de largo plazo, en nuestro caso el año: `longterm_period=365`

```
AnomalyDetectionVec(t, 
                    max_anoms=0.02, 
                    period=round(365/4), 
                    longterm_period=365,
                    direction='both', 
                    plot=TRUE)
```

Y ahora sí, vemos algunas anomalías más adecuadas con la gráfica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero no es rara esa respuesta? Le he pasado algortimos de detección de anomalías menos robustos y los pequeños picos los coge como una anomalía, que me parece lo mas razonable

Comment: @SantiagoMarínAgudelo, verifica mi ultima edición. Saludos.

Comment: Ya te entendí, muchas gracias Patricio me haz aclarado mucho el panorama. De verdad que gracias.